# Testify failing assertion for mocks when passing the correct args

Tags: go, testify

Golang beginner here. I am trying to write tests for my struct which eventually mocks out the stats interface. The relevant part of my code looks below as far as the tests go.

```
// Test code
type MockStats struct {
    mock.Mock
}

func (m *MockStats) Mean(input []float64) (mean float64, err error) {
    args := m.Called(input)
    return (args.Get(0)).(float64), args.Error(1)
}

func TestCalculateWhenErrorCalculatingMean(t *testing.T) {

    m := new(MockStats)

    data := []float64{0.0, 0.1}
    r := ResponseAggregate{ExecutionTimes: data}

    // Expectations
    m.On("Mean", []float64{0.0, 0.1}).Return(float64(0.1), errors.New("Oops!")).Once()
    m.AssertExpectations(t)

    // Function call

    err := r.Calculate(m)

    // Data assertion
    assert.NotNil(t, err)
    if assert.Error(t, err) {
        assert.Equal(t, errors.New("error calculating average. Oops!"), err)
    }

}
```

My calling code looks like

```
type ResponseAggregate struct {
    ExecutionTimes             []float64
    AverageTime                float64
}


func (response *ResponseAggregate) Calculate(stats Stats) error {

    average, err := stats.Mean(response.ExecutionTimes)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("error calculating average. %v", err)
    }

    return nil
```

When I run my tests, I get the error

```
            The code you are testing needs to make 1 more call(s).
```

Could you help me out with what I am missing here? Thanks. BTW, using Go 1.16.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually calling `m.AssertExpectation(t)` before the call `r.Calculate(m)` is made. Thus, you try to check for the mocked method call before the method was called.

Just put the assertion after `r.Calculate(m)` and it should be fine.